# jQuery or Javascript Select menu replacement plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a looking for a stable and actively maintained javascript select menu plugin.  I've used a few in the past but at some point the maintainer moves on and the github issues begin to stack up...

I've looked at:

- https://github.com/gfranko/jquery.selectBoxIt.js (last release 10/2013)
- https://github.com/select2/select2 (last release 11/2017)
- https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen (last release 6/2018)
- https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu (last release 9/2016)

All of these have their pros and cons - chosen is probably the most actively maintained.  At this point I'm looking for *any other* suggestions from developers who've had first hand experience with other plug-ins like these.

Comment: If you don't find one, please fork one, fix the issues & maintain it ;-) Great question; marked a favo(u)rite

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Syncfusion [JavaScript Dropdown list](https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/dropdown-list). It has all the features from select2. It is a commercial product, however, there is a [free community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) is available

Comment: That one looks ok.. a bit buggy in Firefox when scrolling with option groups.  Also, I don't like that it's not open source and that I need to create an account just to download it.  But thanks for the suggestion all the same

Comment: @billynoah this got fixed in recent version. Thanks for the feedback.